# Least mean square linear regression with discrete values on y-axis

Tags: python, regression

So, the idea is that I have floating point numbers on x-axis and discrete values (colors) on y-axis. X-axis stands for measured values (temperature) and y-axis stands for predicted values (colors), where each value is a range of colors. Suppose 10 - 20 degrees Celsius = green color, 20 - 30 degrees = orange color, 30 - 40 degrees = red color. Can I apply LMS linear regression on this? Is there some else more suitable for my case? What confuses me is that either I apply or don't apply LMSLR is '1-1' equation I won't see any change...

Comment: Why are you binning the temperature instead of predicting the temperature value?

Comment: I am really confused, what do you suggest?

Comment: Don’t predict a color of green; predict a temperature of $11$ degrees. // If your customer made a mistake and gave you the colors instead of the numbers, ask for the numbers. If that is impossible, then this is some kind of *ordinal regression* and should be approached as such, and you would be justified in being annoyed with your customer for destroying temperature information.

Comment: And then I match them to colors, within ranges?

Comment: Or not. Report that the predicted temperature is $19$ degrees. Your customer can decide if that is firmly green or if it is close enough to orange to warrant further investigation. // It might be helpful to say what you’re trying to do. In other words, why predict any of this?

Comment: So I have an image from thermal camera, that gets colors and I need to match the colors I see with real temperatures... I have matched 2 measurements and I was thinking of using LMSLR... Any ideas? Is there any better solution?

Comment: For instance I have mapped 25.5 Celsius to color_1 and 45.6 Celsius to color_2. How do I match the rest temperatures to colors? Any ideas?